# Firefox Zoom always gets reset?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox (68.0.1 (64-bit)), I have changed some options for the zoom options:

In "View" tab, I have *deselected* "Zoom Text Only", so the entire page (including images) zooms in/out as I zoom.

I have also tweaked the about:config to the following:

`browser.zoom.full` set to `false` 
`browser.zoom.siteSpecific` set to `false`

However, when I close and re-open FireFox, the "Zoom Text Only" gets selected, and the `browser.zoom.full` resets to `TRUE`.

Why is it not remembering my settings?

Edit: I know there are extensions to help with this, but I'd prefer to figure it out from the FireFox settings without Third-Party requirements.

Edit2: I checked the `prefs.js` in the Profiles folder, and it appears to have saved with `false`:

[image]

Comment: Try running Firefox as Administrator, save the settings and see if they now "stick". I've had similar issues with 7-Zip & Notepad++, setting file associations, that are made permanent only as Admin.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Good idea, but doesn't seem to stick :(.  I've also edited and checked that `prefs.js` is not in Read Only mode...

Comment: It's common for Firefox to change values in about:config on its own.  You can attempt to override it using locked preferences, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Is there more than one profile?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - There's two, "mine" (`asd123.MyName-12345`) and a `k6sy8923.default`

Comment: Try closing Firefox and rename the profile that is not in use, then restarting the browser.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Hm, despite being an Administrator, it's saying I require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to that folder. Maybe I can just delete it...Edit: `About:profiles` only shows one profile, mine.

Comment: That is suspicious; *you* own `C:\Users\<batman>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ `. Check TaskManager to see if there is *another instance* of Firefox running though you've closed it. Also try LockHunter to see what is locking the alternate profile.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - No other instance of Firefox is running. Norton Security is locking the file and I can't unlock, nor force quite Norton (I get the same permission denied error).  I'm going to copy a firefox user profile I have on another computer, paste in to this FireFox Profiles folder and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the Profiles folder, closed FireFox, deleted the `prefs.js` file, then went "up" a folder to just

```
C:\Users\B.Wayne\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

Then right clicked my profile folder (`6a45k87e.BWayne-1562154485368`).  This had the "Read-Only" tick box marked where some files are read-only. I cleared out the box (meaning, nothing is Read-Only), and Apply.

Then restarted FireFox, and so far it seems to be remembering my preferences.